# Maven Release Build Error in Hudson

Tags: maven, hudson, maven-release-plugin

When I do the snapshot build for project the build is successful in Hudson. But when we do the hudson release build we see the error below. Please let me know if any have any idea on this.. Appreciate for your help.

```
[INFO] Constructing Javadoc information...
[INFO] Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_30
[INFO] Building tree for all the packages and classes...
[INFO] Generating /devl/iw/tools/hudson/jobs/Imaging/workspace/Imaging/target/checkout/target/apidocs/ntnood/iw/imaging/client/CommConstants.html...
[INFO] Generating /devl/iw/tools/hudson/jobs/Imaging/workspace/Imaging/target/checkout/target/apidocs/ntnood/iw/imaging/client/DocumentClient.html...
[INFO] Generating /devl/iw/tools/hudson/jobs/docsol/workspace/docsol/target/checkout/target/apidocs/ntnood/iw/imaging/imagegear/class-use/ImageGearException.html...
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] 1 warning
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[INFO] Exit code: 1 - com.sun.tools.javac.file.BaseFileObject$CannotCreateUriError: [DashoPro-V2.2-110100.11101A0148]
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$SourceFileObject.toUri(ClassReader.java:2325)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl.containingPackage(ClassDocImpl.java:297)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.LinkFactoryImpl.getClassToolTip(LinkFactoryImpl.java:140)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.LinkFactoryImpl.getClassLink(LinkFactoryImpl.java:63)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.links.LinkFactory.getLinkOutput(LinkFactory.java:116)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDocletWriter.getLink(HtmlDocletWriter.java:1727)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.AbstractExecutableMemberWriter.addParam(AbstractExecutableMemberWriter.java:126)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.AbstractExecutableMemberWriter.addParameters(AbstractExecutableMemberWriter.java:195)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.AbstractExecutableMemberWriter.addSummaryLink(AbstractExecutableMemberWriter.java:97)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.AbstractMemberWriter.addSummaryLink(AbstractMemberWriter.java:135)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.AbstractMemberWriter.addMemberSummary(AbstractMemberWriter.java:567)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.MemberSummaryBuilder.buildSummary(MemberSummaryBuilder.java:321)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.MemberSummaryBuilder.addSummary(MemberSummaryBuilder.java:378)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.MemberSummaryBuilder.buildMethodsSummary(MemberSummaryBuilder.java:277)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractBuilder.invokeMethod(AbstractBuilder.java:148)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractBuilder.build(AbstractBuilder.java:103)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractMemberBuilder.build(AbstractMemberBuilder.java:76)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractBuilder.buildChildren(AbstractBuilder.java:129)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.buildMemberSummary(ClassBuilder.java:333)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractBuilder.invokeMethod(AbstractBuilder.java:148)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractBuilder.build(AbstractBuilder.java:103)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractBuilder.buildChildren(AbstractBuilder.java:129)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.buildClassDoc(ClassBuilder.java:145)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractBuilder.invokeMethod(AbstractBuilder.java:148)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.AbstractBuilder.build(AbstractBuilder.java:103)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(ClassBuilder.java:117)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:183)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:183)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:125)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:41)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:291)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:165)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:374)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:162)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
[INFO] Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0: [DashoPro-V2.2-110100.11101A0148]
[INFO]  at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2825)
[INFO]  at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2998)
[INFO]  at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3082)
[INFO]  at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3040)
[INFO]  at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:824)
[INFO]  at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$SourceFileObject.toUri(ClassReader.java:2323)
[INFO]  ... 53 more

[INFO] 
[INFO] Command line was: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages
[INFO] 
[INFO] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '/devl/iw/tools/hudson/jobs/docsol/workspace/docsol/target/checkout/target/apidocs' dir.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 24 seconds
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 21 12:35:22 EDT 2014
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 52M/711M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HUDSON] Archiving /devl/iw/tools/hudson/jobs/docsol/workspace/docsol/pom.xml to /devl/iw/tools/hudson/jobs/docsol/modules/ntnood.iw$docsol/builds/2014-08-21_12-34-04/archive/ntnood.iw/docsol/2.3.23-SNAPSHOT/pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
```

Comment: Have you read the stack trace yourself?

Comment: Yes. I see its getting failed while doing javadoc. But its working perfectly when I run the same in my eclipse. We see the issue only in Hudson when we do the release build

Comment: Did you really say "works on my machine!"? So it's probably an environment issue (JDK or OS). First ensure that javadoc can be generated without maven-release-plugin, e.g. by adding `javadoc:javadoc` to the goals and options. Let us know if this succeeds or not.

Comment: javadoc is failed when I ran that manually in unix server (where the hudson is installed). How do I disable the javadoc for maven-release-build in hudson?

Comment: We are using Maven 2.2.1 plugin in our hudson.

Comment: The message is `[INFO] Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0: [DashoPro-V2.2-110100.11101A0148]`...I would suggest to test it on command line on the same machine...Furthermore don't compare eclipse with command line nor with Hudons/Jenkins. Apart from that why using Maven 2.2.1 ...not Maven 3...

Comment: When I test the same on command line on the same machine I see the same error. I'm not sure why we are seeing only Maven 2.2.1 in the drop down while creating the jobs in hudson.